# How to use same directory structure at same time, as two users are logged at same time?

Tags: bash, linux-mint, symlink, cinnamon

I have a Java EE Web project that stay on `~/git/project` directory. This project depends on some relative path configuration made by system vars. Like the var `$PROJECT_HOME` that is pointed to `~/git/project`. This configurations are seen by Intellij Idea IDE.

I wish I could run two branchs at the same time, but without change the configuration. It's like if I have two users logged at same time using different directories but with same relative path and with the same Window Manager or as if an instance were running in a virtual machine. But I want to run it natively. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run two branches at the same time, you need to have both branches checked out somewhere (or compiled and deployed to your Java application container) at the same time.  This necessarily implies that you will need to have two concurrent filesystem hierarchies; one for each branch.